# Column ___ of relation ___ does not exist in csv migration -- is Liquibase ignoring the schema I configured?

Tags: postgresql, csv, liquibase

edit: I fought this too long and went with SQL insert statements instead, since I was generating the CSV from a JS script it was easy to translate over. I think there's a bug in this `loadData` command. Asked the same question in Liqubibase forums and got no responses. I recommend using Flyway instead of Liquibase, seems to be more active.

I'm trying to insert csv data. My config looks like this:

```
 {
            "description": "DS-5001: insert boundary data",
            "tagDatabase": {
              "tag": "v2.1.0"
            },
            "loadData": {
              "dbms": "postgresql",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "id",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "name",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "state_id",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "state_abbr",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "state_name",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "country_code",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "country_name",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "column": {
                    "name": "geom",
                    "type": "STRING"
                  }
                }
              ],
              "commentLineStartsWith": "//",
              "encoding": "UTF-8",
              "file": "../csv/0000-geom-data.csv",
              "quoteChar": "\"",
              "schemaName": "boundaries_justincollum",
              "relativeToChangelogFile": true,
              "separator": ",",
              "tableName": "boundary_area",
              "usePreparedStatements": true
            }
          },
```

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE boundaries_justincollum.boundary_area (
    id varchar NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar NOT NULL,
    state_id varchar NOT NULL,
    state_abbr varchar NOT NULL,
    state_name varchar NOT NULL,
    country_code varchar NOT NULL,
    country_name varchar NOT NULL,
    geom varchar NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_county2 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

But when I run the migration I get an error:

```
        "23-09-21 17:03:15] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Migration failed for changeset changelog/changesets/000210_add_geoms.json::000210::jcollum:",
        "son: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block",
        "aused by: ERROR: column \"\"id\"\" of relation \"boundary_area\" does not exist",
        "ition: 48",
```

(The logs are a little messed up because it's running in an AWS ambda that's running locally.)

In fact it can't find any of the columns in the `boundary_area` table (many similar entries in the logs, column ___ of relation ___ does not exist). But when I select them it's fine:

```
SELECT id FROM boundaries_justincollum.boundary_area ma LIMIT 10;  -- returns 10 rows!
```

command line:

```
JAVA_OPTS=\"-Xms2048m -Xmx4096m\" liquibase update --url=jdbc:postgresql://[redacted]?currentSchema=boundaries_justincollum,public --default-schema-name=boundaries_justincollum --username=*** --password=*** --changelog-file=\"changelog/index.json\" --log-level=INFO"
```

It's acting like it's looking in the public schema -- the table does not exist in the public schema. I built a very similar migration using sql files (we have about 20 existing migrations like that) and it worked fine. But as soon as I tried to use `loadData` I started encountering issues.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Liquibase's `loadData`? I have another migration that is inserting large amounts of data but it's using `INSERT INTO ...` with a a generated SQL file. That works fine. But I'd rather keep the data in CSV, that's easier to edit.

Comment: I'm surprised there's no `liquibase` tag

Comment: I assume that is because that is not about database administration, but about development. Try Stackoverflow.

Comment: We use liquibase to manage database migrations. That sure seems like database administration.

Comment: I have added the tag for you.

Comment: thanks for the help :)